# How can i add custom fields in shopify add product page?

Tags: php, shopify

i am making a shopify store and want to add custom html and image upload when adding new product, something like this image

[image]

as far as i know you cannot add custom html by any metfields plugins( correct me if i am wrong ). do you know any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom HTML fields using the [Metafield Manager](https://apps.shopify.com/metafields-manager) or [SuperFields](https://apps.shopify.com/superfields) app.

You just click the More Actions dropdown and that's where you can add your content.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying, but is there any other way of doing this without using  any app

Comment: @atul1039 I believe the only other option is to use http://shopifyfd.com/ which is a browser extension for Chrome. I've never used this tough so don't really know how it works.

Comment: @atul1039 According to Shopify's support documentation (https://help.shopify.com/manual/products/metafields) "To create, edit, or delete metafields, you need to use an app. The Shopify App Store has a number of metafield apps. You can also use the Metafield API to create your own app."

Answer (score 1):

Hello there you don't need any app for this you can use the [Shopify UI Elements Generator](https://ui-elements-generator.myshopify.com/pages/line-item-property) tool to easily generate the HTML and Liquid code for each form field that you want to add to your cart page. This tool was created by Shopify to help simplify the process of adding custom user interface elements, such as form fields and icons, to Shopify themes.

Answer (score 1):

**Product metafields can also be managed from the Shopify adminpanel directly. You don't need a third-party app or chrome extension anymore!**

From the adminpage, go to settings (bottomleft corner) and go to Metafields. From there, you can add the metafields to the product and set the desired contenttype (inputfield, image upload, checkbox, etcetera)

You will need to provide a namespace and key, which you can refer to from the code template. For instance:
setting the "namespace and key" field to `my_custom_fields.somefield`, you will be able to access it from the product template file (product.liquid) like so:
`{{ product.metafields.my_custom_fields.somefield }}` or, of course, assign it like so: `{% assign myField = product.metafields.my_custom_fields.somefield %}`

The created metafields will appear on the product editpage at the bottom. No chrome extensions needed!!